# Display a loader image and text when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, loading

I have the following **JavaScript question** (eventhough it is Hudson-related):

There is this multiframed web page with several "tabs" at the top -

[image]

And most "tabs" (but not the first ones) contain numerous Google charts, which take longer time to render, esp. in Internet Explorer, appearing to freeze the browser -

[image]

If I could display a loader image and message, when a "tab" is clicked it would be much better user experience:

[image]

I've found and can modify this Hudson *HTMP Publishing plugin* file:

**/var/lib/hudson/plugins/htmlpublisher/WEB-INF/classes/htmlpublisher/HtmlPublisher/header.html**

```
function updateBody(tabId, page) {
    document.getElementById(selectedTab).setAttribute("class", "unselected");
    tab = document.getElementById(tabId)
    tab.setAttribute("class", "selected");
    selectedTab = tabId;
    iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
    iframe.src = tab.getAttribute("value");
}
```

The above `updateBody()` method refers to this piece of HTML, which I can't modify:

```
<ul id="tabnav">
<li id="tab1" class="selected" onclick="updateBody('tab1');" value="FinalReport.html">FinalReport</li>
<li id="tab2" class="unselected" onclick="updateBody('tab2');" value="SummaryReport.html">SummaryReport</li>
<li id="tab3" class="unselected" onclick="updateBody('tab3');" value="CalRunnerReport.html">CalRunnerReport</li>
<li id="tab4" class="unselected" onclick="updateBody('tab4');" value="CalRunnerReportStatistics.html">CalRunnerReportStatistics</li>
<li id="tab5" class="unselected" onclick="updateBody('tab5');" value="GSM_CAL.html">GSM_CAL</li>
<li id="tab6" class="unselected" onclick="updateBody('tab6');" value="EDGE_CAL.html">EDGE_CAL</li>
<li id="tab7" class="unselected" onclick="updateBody('tab7');" value="LTE_CAL.html">LTE_CAL</li>
<li id="tab8" class="unselected" onclick="updateBody('tab8');" value="WCDMA_CAL.html">WCDMA_CAL</li>
<li id="tab9" class="unselected" onclick="updateBody('tab9');" value="LTE_TXV3_CAL.html">LTE_TXV3_CAL</li>
<li id="tab10" class="unselected" onclick="updateBody('tab10');" value="WCDMA_TXV3_CAL.html">WCDMA_TXV3_CAL</li>
<li id="tab11" class="unselected" onclick="updateBody('tab11');" value="LTE_VER.html">LTE_VER</li>
<li id="tab12" class="unselected" onclick="updateBody('tab12');" value="WCDMA_VER.html">WCDMA_VER</li>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("hudson_link").innerHTML="Back to Station18622_Manual_Trigger";</script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("hudson_link").href="/job/Station18622_Manual_Trigger/";</script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("zip_link").href="*zip*/HTML_Report.zip";</script>
</ul>
```

Could anybody please suggest a modification to the `updateBody()` method to display a "loading..." message to the user?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried adding the following to the `header.html`, but it didn't really work (image wasn't visible at any moment):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function updateBody(tabId, page) {
    $('#wait').show();
    document.getElementById(selectedTab).setAttribute("class", "unselected");
    tab = document.getElementById(tabId)
    tab.setAttribute("class", "selected");
    selectedTab = tabId;
    iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
    iframe.src = tab.getAttribute("value");
    $('#wait').hide();
}
```

..........

```
<h1><a id="hudson_link" href="#"></a><img id="wait" src="/images/loader.gif" width="32" height="32"></h1>
<h2><a id="zip_link" href="#">Zip</a></h2>

<ul id="tabnav">
```

Answer (score 0):

The "..is not responding due to a long-running script" message tells you that your long-running script is blocking the ui, meaning that even if you try displaying a loading image, it won't move since the ui will be stuck.

You haven't posted the code that runs after you switch a tab, but that might be the issue in the first place.